# How to display same background color when sheet is opened?

Tags: swiftui

I have a page which has a dark blue background color. When a button is pressed, a sheet is opened, however behind the sheet the blue background shifts down and it shows a white background. How can I prevent this?

```
ZStack {
            
            setBackgroundColor.darkBlue
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)

HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        self.showSheet = true
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Add exercise")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(height: 10)
                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.darkBlue)
                            .padding()
                            .background(CustomColor.cyan)
                    }
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                        AddWorkoutSheet()
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
}
```

[Blue background shifted when sheet is opened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EngdD.png)

I have tried to find out what is wrong, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I quite new to programming and SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

It is not shifting down, it is just how sheet works. When you toggle a sheet, it will pop out from the bottom with a default white background, therefore covering the background of your root view. So what you want might be a transparent sheet. If this is the case, using sheet may not be the best way as implementing a transparent sheet needs some walkaround. You may instead try using a transition to move the view up or down with offset.